# Old Jboss installation. Is it safer behind a reverse proxy?

Tags: web-application

I have an old Jboss 4.2 installation that is directly exposed on the internet. Programmers are updating the web application code to make it compatible with a supported version of WildFly, but at the moment I have to keep this old application server alive. 
I read that there are some severe vulnerabilities regarding Jboss 4.x, so I was wondering if putting it behind an updated reverse proxy (instead of directly exposing it) could make the installation safer. Maybe I can track and possibly block hacking attempts using the reverse proxy?

Comment: Hello J.B. and welcome to Stack Exchange. I believe that your question is similar in nature to [this question regarding the effectiveness of reverse proxies](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/259/how-effective-are-reverse-proxies-as-a-web-application-security-measure). In short, it might help a little bit, but your best path of action is to make deployment to an up-to-date server software *absolute priority*.

Comment: Thanks @MechMK1, your link introduced me to the world of WAF (Web application firewall), that I have never heard about. However I will upgrade the server software ASAP.

Comment: I'm glad it was helpful to you. I hope everything works out well for you and your team.